# Adding numbers whose sum is greater than 10 in brainfuck

Tags: brainfuck

Is there an efficient algorithm that determine the sum of two numbers, even if these numbers are greater than ten?

Answer (score 2):

the user can only enter the numbers one digit at a time. Assuming only positive numbers can be entered the algorithm to parse it is as follows.

```
initialize accumulator to 0
for each digit the user enters
    multiply the accumulator by 10
    add the new digit to the accumulator
```

You will need to handle when the user enters the enter key to finish entering the number, and the above algorithm only works for numbers up to 255 (assuming 8 bit cells).

From then on you have a cell with a number. Do this again to get a cell with another number, then you can simply add them together normally.

Answer (score 0):

Using http://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/ you can see the value of each cell numerically, not having to use all that dumb ASCII conversion stuff. Then, just program in your inputs and the algorithm.

```
++++++>+++++ 6 plus 5
[<+>-]
```

Adds one to 6 and subtracts one from 5 each iteration, making 11.
The visualizer will show that the cell is 11.
If you want to preserve the y value, add a "temp" cell

```
++++++>+++++>[-] #0: 6 #1: 5 #2: 0
<[<+>>+<-]
>[<+>-]
```